# How to write path that requires username and password?

Tags: c#

I want to perform file copying from local HDD to a server
- to access the server it require to insert username and password,
 at manual when I write the server name: \neoserver a window popup and after inserting username and password all the server's file appeared.
to perform the copying I use the command: File.copy(source path, destination path)
how can I write the server's path in a way it won't require user@pass???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to call the `copy` command line executable with the right credentials and parameters.

For best control, use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) to supply all the information needed:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("copy");
startInfo.Arguments = "source dest";
startInfo.UserName = myUser;
startInfo.Password = myPassword;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```